# No bottom lines for last row of tags in next tag badge popup

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, tag-badges

In [your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) you can track your next tag badge.

In some cases there are not bottom lines for tag blocks in next tag badge popup:

> [image]

Animation with scrolling popup content:

> [image]

Reproduced on iPad Pro 11", Windows 11 both in Google Chrome.

At the same time in other tabs bottom lines are visible:

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Chrome on Windows 10. Can you use the browser inspector to see what's happening there?

Comment: @Joachim what exactly can I get from browser inspector to move forward on the issue?